# How to put RequestParam value as URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have some input fields in my jsp page,l want to know is it possible for values passed in those fields to be passed as URL.

I tried using @RequestParam and @PathVariable on same variable to try to retrive it and put it as URI but it didnt work

This is my jsp page form:

```
<body>
 <form action="welcome/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="">
  <input type="submit"  value="go">
 </form>
</body>
```

And this is my Controller handler method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/welcome/{name}")
public String welcomeAgain(@PathVariable @RequestParam("name")String name){
    return "welcome";
}
```

Comment: why would you want to get them as url? if you want that you should use GET method not POST and change the controller to use @GetMapping and the requestparam should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value passed in URL you can use `@PathVariable` normally with `GET` request.

```
http://localhost:8080/user/101
```

`@RequestParam` normally used with `POST` request for accessing the query parameter values

```
http://localhost:8080/user/101?param1=10&param2=20
```

---

```
@PostMapping(value = "/welcome/{name}")
public String welcomeAgain(@PathVariable("name") String name){
    return "welcome " + name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `@PathVariable("name")` annotation. Exclude the `@RequestParam` annotation from your function.

I hope it helps.